# Interactive overlay of multiple histograms in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have multiple plots to show that overlap each other.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5]
b = [5,4,4,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1]
c = [4,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,10,10]

x_min, x_max = min(a + b + c), max(a + b + c)

plt.hist(a, range=(x_min,x_max), bins = 10, alpha=0.5, label="a")
plt.hist(b, range=(x_min,x_max), bins = 10, alpha=0.5, label="b")
plt.hist(c, range=(x_min,x_max), bins = 10, alpha=0.5, label="c")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Is it possible for me to generate all the individual plots in one step, then allow the user to interactively choose which to overlay in a second step?

In this example, a correct solution would have three interactive check boxes (one fore each plot). Because there are 3 check boxes, there are 2^3=8 possible ways the user could specify the plot.

Comment: You can use the [CheckButtons](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.CheckButtons) method. Have you tried to implement this? What were the specific problems?

Comment: None of the examples of CheckButtons I found work. For example, there does not seem to be a set_visability attribute for histograms, which is required for this use case. 

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/check_buttons.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you have to write your own function. Matplotlib `hist()` returns a [BarContainer](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/container_api.html?highlight=barcontainer#matplotlib.container.BarContainer) - a fancy name for a list of rectangle objects, i.e, the bars of the histogram. We can set the visibility of each rectangle like we can set the visibility of each line in a line plot. An implementation therefore could look like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import CheckButtons


def select_plots(list_of_inputs, labels=list("abcdefghijklmn"), bins=10):
    #list_of_input and labels must have the same length
    nr_of_hists=len(list_of_inputs)
    labels = labels[:nr_of_hists]
      
    x_min, x_max = min(min(l) for l in list_of_inputs), max(max(l) for l in list_of_inputs)
    #collect list of barcontainers generated by hist plots
    barcontainers = []
    fig, ax  = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
    for label, list in zip(labels, list_of_inputs):
        _, _, curr_barcontainer  = ax.hist(list, range=(x_min,x_max), bins=bins, alpha=0.5, label=label) 
        barcontainers.append(curr_barcontainer)
    
    #create checkboxes and color them to correspond with the plot
    ax_chkbox = plt.axes([0.8, 0.9-0.05*nr_of_hists, 0.1, 0.05*nr_of_hists])
    check_boxes = CheckButtons(ax_chkbox, labels, np.ones(nr_of_hists, dtype=bool))  
    handles, _ = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    for rect, handle in zip(check_boxes.rectangles, handles):
        rect.set_facecolor(handle.get_facecolor())

    #redraw figure when checkbox status has changed
    def chkboxcall(label):
        for barcontainer, status in zip(barcontainers, check_boxes.get_status()):
            [rect.set_visible(status) for rect in barcontainer]
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()            
            
    #connect widget function   
    check_boxes.on_clicked(chkboxcall)   
    plt.show()
    #return last status of checkboxes after figure has been closed  
    return [i for i, status in enumerate(check_boxes.get_status()) if status]   


#input lists with their corresponding label names
a = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6]
b = [5,4,4,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1]
c = [4,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,10,10]

all_lists = [a, b, c]
all_labels = ["a", "b", "c"]
#bins can be integers or ranges like [0, 2, 6, 7, 10]
bins = 10

idx = select_plots(all_lists, all_labels, bins)

print("The following data are valid:", *[all_labels[i] for i in idx])
```

Sample output:
[image]

```
>>>The following data are valid: a c
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with referring to line examples for histograms is that histograms are actually the composition of multiple lines. This means, when the button is called, you need to loop over the lines to get the expected behavior.

In the following example we see how we loop over each part p of the histogram. We change the transparency depending on its current value. Note: `%matplotlib qt` is required for jupyter notebook.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import CheckButtons
%matplotlib qt 

### Specify Data And Range
a = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5]
b = [5,4,4,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1]
c = [4,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,10,10]

x_min, x_max = min(a + b + c), max(a + b + c)

### Create Plots
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

p1 = ax.hist(a, range=(x_min,x_max), bins = 10, alpha=0.3, label="a")[2]
p2 = ax.hist(b, range=(x_min,x_max), bins = 10, alpha=0.3, label="b")[2]
p3 = ax.hist(c, range=(x_min,x_max), bins = 10, alpha=0.3, label="c")[2]
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2)

plots = [p1, p2, p3]

# Make Check Buttons
rax    = plt.axes([0.05, 0.4, 0.1, 0.15])
labels = ["a", "b", "c"]
check  = CheckButtons(rax, labels)

def action(label, default_transparency = 0.3):
    
    index = labels.index(label)
    for p in plots[index]:
        if p.get_alpha() == default_transparency:
            p.set_alpha(0.0)
        else:
            p.set_alpha(default_transparency)
        
    plt.draw()

### Run Widget
check.on_clicked(action)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```